# Why is shape empty?

Tags: python, numpy

This code creates a 10-element array.

1. Why is size 1? Shouldn't it be 0?
2. why is shape empty? Shouldn't it be 1 dimension?

```
    In [14]: s = np.array(10)                                                                            

    In [15]: s                                                                                           
    Out[15]: array(10)

    In [16]: s.size                                                                                      
    Out[16]: 1

    In [17]: s.shape                                                                                     
    Out[17]: ()
```

Comment: No this makes a single element array. `arange(10)` and `ones(10)` make 10 element arrays.

Comment: If it *was* a 10 element array, why would its size be 0?

Comment: @hpaulj Is a single element array's shape empty ()?

Comment: `numpy` arrays can be 0d, 1d, 2d and on up to 32.  The `shape` is a tuple, with one value per dimension.  `(10,)` is a 1 element tuple, `()` is a 0 element tuple.  `np.array(10)` is a 0d array, `np.array([10])` is 1d, `np.array([[10]])` is 2d.

Answer (score 5):

If one calls `np.array()` on arbitrary object that is not iterable, numpy silently creates an empty array with no dimensions.
However, its size is 1.

[Docs of numpy size](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.size.html) tell us that x.size is equivalent to calling `np.prod(x.shape)`. And [docs for np.prod](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.prod.html) state that calling np.prod on empty sequence gives us 1. Probably it is so due to the fact that 1 is a neutral element for multiplication, meaning the following.

Say you have an array `[4, 2, 3]`. Its elements product is `24`. Now you split it in two arrays: `[4]` and `[2, 3]`. You have a nice property: `np.prod([4, 2, 3]) == np.prod([4]) * np.prod([2, 3])`. But if one of the arrays is empty, you want this property still hold: `np.prod([4, 2, 3]) == np.prod([]) * np.prod([4, 2, 3])`.

Comment: " silently creates an empty array", np.array(10)--- Does this create an empty array or a one-element array? If it is a one-element array, then it must have a dimension? Or as @hapaulj said, it is a 0-dimension array.

Comment: @marlon No, it is an empty array. It has no elements. If you try calling s[0], it raises an error.

Comment: @soobus, are we looking at 'np.array(10)', not 'np.array()'? Is the former an empty array?

Comment: @marlon Yes. Try calling np.array(np.array). Or np.array(int). Or np.array("meow"). They all are not array-like and therefore give the same result -- an array with no elements and empty dimensions.

Comment: np.array(10) --- Is this an array "with no elements"? If true, what's the purpose of creating this array?

Comment: @marlon there is no "purpose", just "guaranteed behavior". Docs tell us what happens if you pass there iterable, and do not tell anything else. So behavior could be any. It could throw error, for example, but for some reason stays silent.